# How to mount without mkdir

Tags: mount, mountpoint

Very very basic conceptual question. (Obviously from a beginner)

I want to manually mount an internal hard drive.

My drive in not mounted.

dir /media is empty.

I click on the drive in the GUI, it mounts.

Now /media has /media/myDrive

myDrive is sda

But, to manually mount my drive using mount, I know I am supposed the mkdir mountpoint in advance, so that I can do

```
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/myDrive
```

**Question:** 
How come if I use the GUI, the mountpoint does not need to exist in advance?

If I want to mount my drive in a script, do I absolutely must mkdir /media/myDrive in advance?

Many thanks for clarifying a newbie misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI does the `mkdir` in advance for you. It deletes it when it's done.

You don't need to mount to `/media/name/`, there is a special folder called `/mnt` in your hard drive.

Answer (score 6):

When you mount a volume using the Nautilus GUI file manager, the operation is handled by the gvfs daemon rather than a traditional `mount` command.

You can call `gvfs-mount` manually from the command line in which case the volume will be mounted in exactly the same way (without the need to explicitly create a mount point) at the default gvfs location - either /media or /media/*username* - plus the device label. For example

```
$ gvfs-mount -d /dev/sda1
Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/28C68BC3C68B8FAC
```

To unmount, use the mountpoint and volume label

```
$ gvfs-mount -u /media/28C68BC3C68B8FAC/
```